# MinGW Main routine

Tags: function, compiler-construction, mingw, startup, program-entry-point

In C there is no main program. Sure, C programmers begin with int main(int argc char *argv[]), but this only works because there is a routine that tells the compiler/IDE to run the function named main first.

I can't seem to find this routine in MinGW, though. Where is it defined? I just searched because I wanted to change it (only as a test) and play around with it a bit. Can someone link me to the correct file in the MinGW folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ld` linker will look for a match of one of several symbols to use as the entry point when linking a PE file:

```
entry point              subsystem
---------------------   --------------

NtProcessStartup           native
WinMainCRTStartup          Windows GUI
mainCRTStartup             Windows CUI (console)
__PosixProcessStartup      POSIX CUI
WinMainCRTStartup          WinCE GUI
mainCRTStartup             Xbox
mainCRTStartup             other

DllMainCRTStartup@12 (or possibly DllMainCRTStartup) for DLLs
```

MinGW will have an object file that gets automatically linked in that has the actual PE entry point. - you can see what object files are being automatically linked in by using gcc's `-v` option.

In a quick test using MinGW 4.6.1 building a console subsystem "hello world" program, the object file containing the entry point is `crt2.o` and it has a symbol `mainCRTStartup` that is picked up by the linker as the entry point.

The source file containing the entrypoint code is `crtexe.c` (or `crtdll.c`).

You can override the entry point using the `--entry` option to the linker (`Wl,--entry=whatever` when used on the gcc command line).

Comment: Thanks! I will play around with gcc a bit.